# Is the sine function periodic in $x$ or $y$?

Tags: signal-processing, terminology

I know sine is $2\pi$-periodic, but some people say the motion is "periodic in..."

Would it be periodic in $y$?

If we move along the $x$-axis, the function values $y = \sin(x)$ will repeat, so I think it's "periodic in $y$".

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Don't get hung up on these details of language. One might argue that because $x$ is the independent variable, it moves in arbitrary ways (can be chosen arbitrarily) and so it would make sense to say "the sine function is periodic *in $y$*". But one could also say "the sine function is a periodic function *of $x$*" (because it is a function of $x$).

In the end, whatever you say, people will understand what you're trying to say: "the sine function is a periodic function" omits all details and yet, everyone understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your function is periodic on the interval $2\pi$.

Comment: It's the lingo not the understanding: is it "periodic in y" since the function values y repeat?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes your function $y(x)$ is periodic in $y$ on the interval $x \in [ 0, 2 \pi ]$, since $y(0)=y(2\pi)$.

Comment: I think $y(x)$ is periodic in $x$. For example, if you had a function $z(x,y)$ and $z(0,y)=z(2\pi,y)$ for all $y$ then you would say $z$ is $2\pi$-periodic in $x$. $y(x)$ being periodic in $y$ is a weird idea unless it is somehow implicitly defined and $y$ is a function of itself.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Maybe you are right. I am not an native english speaker.