# When is a dynamical system periodic?

Tags: terminology

Say a system of ODEs describing a dynamical system, with solutions/state-space vectors ($x$, $y$, $\theta$).

If values of $y$ and $\theta$ repeat but values of $x$ do not, would I say that the solutions are periodic in $y$ and theta but not in $x$?

I'm confusing this with [a simple periodic sine function](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35798/is-the-sine-function-periodic-in-x-or-y), I think.

Comment: Is this question different to your first one?

Comment: @convexhull yes, different, but perhaps I could combine both questions into one? This question here is really the one that I'm confused about, in terms of using the correct lingo ...

Comment: What does your solution look like in x direction?

Comment: The usage of the word "in" is probably what's confusing.  The "in" refers to the interval/dimension over which the function repeats.  For instance, you often hear the term "time-periodic" or "periodic in time".  That means that the function $f(t)$ repeats after a particular interval of time along the $t$-axis, not that time itself is periodic.  For phase-space periodicity more precise terminology can be used, e.g., attractor etc.

Answer (score 2):

Like I mentioned in your other question already, don't worry about the language part too much if there is a way to express what you are trying to say in "natural" language (rather than trying to be overly formal). Here, I would say something like this:

> The solution of this dynamical system is periodic in the sense that the $y(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ components of the solution repeat after some time. This is analogous to the position of a marked point on a wobbly wheel of a car when letting $x(t)$ be the position along a straight road, $y(t)$ be the position perpendicular to the road, and $\theta(t)$ the angle of the marked point against the vertical direction: $y(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ are periodic if the car moves at a fixed speed, whereas $x(t)$ is not.

See how I explained the concept without trying to rely on a precisely definition of what "periodic in $y$" or "periodic in $x$" actually means?